# Amending commit HEAD~1 for Gerrit review which shares a file with commit HEAD

Tags: git, gerrit

I made one commit containing multiple files and pushed it into `Gerrit` for a code review. This is `HEAD~1`.

Then I made another commit, also containing multiple files and pushed it into Gerrit for another code review. This is `HEAD`.

Now I realized I need to make a correction to one file for the commit `HEAD~1` but that file was also changed within the more recent `HEAD` commit.

Do I need to make the change to the file for `HEAD~1` without the changes in `HEAD`, commit it, rebase/squash that commit into the `HEAD~1` commit and push it into the same change in Gerrit, and then do the same for the `HEAD` commit?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to move your changes to branches:
This is for example your original log

```
#git log --graph --decorate --oneline -n13
* e40f865 (HEAD, master) Change 2
* 120c061 Change 1
* 73a8f97 Initial commit
```

Now move them into a branch:

```
#git branch changeA 120c061
#git branch changeB e40f865
#git log --graph --decorate --oneline -n13
* e40f865 (HEAD, master, changeB) Change 2
* 120c061 (changeA) Change 1
* 73a8f97 Initial commit
```

As you can see, changeB depends on changeA. Now reset the master so the changes are not in the master but really in the branch:

```
#git reset --hard HEAD~2
HEAD is now at 73a8f97 Initial commit
```

Now, checkout changeA and make you change. The amended commit:

```
#git commit --amend -a
[changeA 93837a4] Change 1
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
#git log --graph --decorate --oneline -n13
* 93837a4 (HEAD, changeA) Change 1
* 73a8f97 (master) Initial commit
```

As you see the change 1 has a new SHA1, next checkout changeB:

```
#git checkout changeB
Switched to branch 'changeB'
#git log --graph --decorate --oneline -n13
* e40f865 (HEAD, changeB) Change 2
* 120c061 Change 1
* 73a8f97 (master) Initial commit
```

Now you see that changeB still depends on the original change 1, you just need to rebase the change to the new change 1.

```
#git rebase 93837a4
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Change 1
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
....
....
Applying: Change 2

#git log --graph --decorate --oneline -n13
* d3fac58 (HEAD, changeB) Change 2
* 93837a4 (changeA) Change 1
* 73a8f97 (master) Initial commit
```

And now you have the updated changeB that depends on the update changeB and you can submit it again to Gerrit for review

Comment: That seems more detailed than my answer. +1

Comment: when i pushed the rebased changed into Gerrit, it made a whole new code review item but i wanted it to amend the existing one.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I assume you have the ChangeID in your commit messages? Did you then use the --amend to amend your commit? Just check if the changeid's have not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: as explained in "[How to amend review issues in Gerrit when there is a second newer review also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487934/6309)"

> When you have dependent reviews in Gerrit (that is, one change in review which is dependent on an earlier change which is simultaneously in review), and you need to make modifications to the earlier change, you effectively have to resubmit both changes (since the second change becomes dependent on a different "parent" commit)

That involves:

- a third commit
- a git rebase -i to reorder the commits
- a `git review` again